# StyleCop+ Advanced Naming Rules, variable naming

Tags: c#, stylecop, naming-conventions

How can I configure a StyleCop+ naming rule, in such a way that my variable name like `controlUI`, `controlHVACTest`, etc. gets validated successfully?

For now, since it is not in `sampleName` format, the StyleCop+ complains about the naming convention.

Also, what is the best way to add custom naming validation rules?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't, maybe you should change the names?

Comment: well, changing "controlHVACTester" something other is feasible, but I'm running StyleCop+ on an existing ode base, so renaming all those variables gonna be much difficult than to adjust the rule itself. The macro for the variable is like `$(AaBb)`, I'm looking forward to a way to adjust the rule something Like, `A*A*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convinient way to allow names like `controlUI` and `controlHVACTest` is to add `UI` and `HVAC` into "Abbreviations" section.

Regarding your question about "changing `AaBb` to `A*B*`" - I'm not sure that I understand what your mean. StyleCop+ naming rules are very flexible indeed, but if you setup your naming template to `$(A)$(*)$(A)$(*)` (which seems similar to what you were talking about) - it will force all names to have at least two capital letters (that do not follow each other).

If you specify your situation a little bit more, I could try to help you setup your naming templates, if possible.

Comment: It seems making `UI` and `HVAC` to abbreviasions list is more feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - you turn off the rule you do not like, you write your own rule.

StyleCop rules are not configurable like you want - you have to replace the rule.

> Also, what is the best way to add custom naming validation rules?

Starts with the documentation.

Alternatively:

http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html

(which I found in google with "Stylecop own rule" as keywords).

Comment: Well, when StyleCop+ gives us an option to edit the rule, I thought we should not turn it off entirely, but to edit the rule according to our own standards like changing `AaBb` to `A*B*`?